# Consume events from multiple MQTT topics with single Paho MQTT client in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, mqtt, paho

I would like to efficiently consume events from multiple MQTT topics in a single route in Apache Camel. The Paho MQTT component seems to support only 1 topic at the moment, while I had expected that you could include multiple topics separated by a comma like with the Kafka component.

[Kafka Component path parameter](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.21.x/kafka-component.html#_path_parameters_1_parameters)

For example, suppose you have the following topics:

- a/b/c0
- a/b/c1
- a/b/..
- a/b/c40

but you are interested in all topics except topic a/b/c40.

One option is to use MQTT topic wildcards and drop the events from topic a/b/c40.
However, the problem is that c40 takes up a lot of bandwidth (95+ %) and this extra load should be avoided.

Another option is to create a consumer route for each topic and connect these routes to the same destination route. However, creating and managing 40 mqtt clients does not seem ideal to me or is the overhead negligible?

A third option is to initialize the MQTT client with client.subscribe(topiclist) before starting the route and then pass the MqttClient via the advanced option 'client'. [Paho Component client option](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.21.x/paho-component.html#_component_option_client)
But I am unsure when the client.connect(connectOptions) method should be executed.
If this connect method is not executed before starting the route, I receive a 'client not connected' error. But when I execute it before starting the route, then it seemed that the route was no longer receiving all messages.

Which option do you think is best?
In the case of the 3rd option, when should the client.connect method be called? Before/After starting the route, in the route ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I went with the **second option**. It is unfortunate but yes the Paho MQTT client on Camel does not support multiple topics in the same route. I have had this exact issue few months back where I had data coming in over MQTT from multiple (10+) production lines and around 5-6 topics per line with decent sized messages (don't remember the exact size but around 2 - 3 KB per message).

I created a configuration CSV and a small gawk script to generate the camel blueprint, this made the management of the routes very simple. I used one camel context per production line. This data was later processed in one destination topic. Performance was not an issue and the application was able to handle messages coming in every 10 - 15 ms.

I usually keep two settings in mind when dealing with high frequency large payloads:

1. set the **maxInflight** property to a high value like 500, 1000 depending on your needs. This ensures no messages are lost due to too many in flight messages.
2. Use a lower **qos**, like 0 or 1. This ensures that the broker does not get backed up too much and its very rare that a message is lost/not delivered.

Only draw back when having so many routes and contexts is that they take some time to start up, but that is not something you would have to do often so its acceptable.

Comment: That is the option that I have also implemented for the time being, but only for 6 topics and therefore 6 MQTT clients. Now there is a new request to also process data from 10+ other topics and since new MQTT clients need to be added I'm starting to doubt this method.

I'm going to further explore the 3rd option in the coming days and better describe in my original question what exactly I tried and what went wrong. If that is not successful, I will probably also continue with this 2nd option.

Comment: I think I will continue with a variant of the 3rd option where the project consists of 2 applications with a shared configuration file. The first application is responsible for creating the client and subscribing to the topics (QoS 1). The clientId is taken from the configuration file. This application should only be run when the subscriptions need to be changed. The second application contains the camel routes and uses the same clientId so that I will also receive the messages from the other topics.

Comment: Ok that also sounds like a good solution!